# linq to stored procedures multiple select

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

MSDN docs say that I can write a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MultipleResultTypesSequentially
AS
select * from products
select * from customers
```

then read it from LINQ like this

```
IMultipleResults sprocResults =
    db.MultipleResultTypesSequentially();

// First read products. 
foreach (Product prod in sprocResults.GetResult<Product>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(prod.ProductID);
}

// Next read customers. 
foreach (Customer cust in sprocResults.GetResult<Customer>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(cust.CustomerID);
}
```

what if one of my select statements return something other then a regular table object - with a join or just selecting certain columns?

how do I let LINQ know that I want to read the next SELECT ??? basically , what I'm wondering is this example from MSDN reading Products first then Customers because they are written in that order in the stored procedure , or is writing `.GetResult<Customer>()` telling c# to find the result that maps to type Customer? and also what would the foreach loop look like for this unknown type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test with a similar stored procedure and found that if your `foreach` loops are not in the correct order, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, so it doesn't look like C# is able to find the correct result based on the type used in `GetResult<>`.

As for your select statement returning something other than a table, if you drag a stored procedure from the Server Explorer onto the Linq to Sql designer, the designer will autogenerate a class based on procedures output.  I created a procedure with a couple of joined tables, neither of which existed in my project, and Linq to Sql created a type for me, named like StoredProcedureNameResult, so a procedure called GetCreditCard had a type named GetCreditCardResult.